# Undefined reference to symbol 'XSetFillStyle'

Tags: x11, make

I'm trying to compile, or make for Esetroot, when I get an error shown here. Is there some kind of command line argument I have to add to make, The header files are added to the c file already, so I am not sure what header file it is missing in X11. my X11-devel, and imlib2-devel is installed.

thanks

```
%userx@voided Esetroot-20030422>$make
cc   -L/usr/lib -lImlib2 -DPIXMAP_SUPPORT -DHAVE_UNISTD_H -o Esetroot Esetroot.c
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccug0Ak3.o: undefined reference to symbol 'XSetFillStyle'
/lib64/libX11.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:15: recipe for target 'Esetroot' failed
make: *** [Esetroot] Error 1
```

header files in C file.

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <X11/Xatom.h>
#include <X11/Xos.h>
#include <Imlib2.h>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`XSetFillStyle`](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man3/XSetFillRule.3.html) function lives in the X11 library (also referred to as "Xlib").

Your example does not show that you use the X11 library, e.g, adding a `-lX11` would help.  (Some configurations require additional libraries):

```
cc  -DPIXMAP_SUPPORT -DHAVE_UNISTD_H -o Esetroot Esetroot.c -lImlib2  -lX11
```